# Spring Cloud Stream- multiple source is single spring boot project

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Can we have multiple Sources in a single SpringCloudStream application, say on main class and three Source Class. Among one can 1.jdbc poller, 2.file poller and another a 3.simple payload class.

So when we define  stream in DataFlowServer for as source, how will it interact and what will be the flow.

Suppose the sink is looking for data from 3rd source.

Answer (score 0):

As a Spring Cloud Stream application, you can define multiple sources in a single application. You can see a sample application on this [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/multi-io)

If you construct a Stream via Spring Cloud Data Flow DSL, multiple source configuration is not directly supported as the stream in Data Flow DSL connects a single destination in the `|` between the applications.

You can still use `Named Destinations` to perform some join operations. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623205/spring-data-flow-w-2-sources-feeding-one-processor-sink) SO answer.